# Angle between PCA vector spaces?

Tags: pca, linear-algebra, eigenvalues, metric

I have two datasets of the same shape, one for condition A, the other for condition B. I would like to test if the major axes of variance of condition A are different than those of B. Here is my idea. For each dataset, take as many PCA's as necessary to have a total explained variance of, for example, 90%. Then I will have two vector spaces: $\{\vec{a}_i\}$ and $\{\vec{b}_j\}$, where each vector is the eigenvector of PCA. Now, the goal would be to calculate the "angle" between the two vector spaces, where small angle would mean that the axes of variance are almost aligned, and large angle would mean that the axes of variance are almost orthogonal.

I have tried formulating this as an optimization problem.

1. Find an arbitrary vector in each vector space.

$\vec{p}_A(\vec{\alpha}) = \sum_i \alpha_i\vec{a}_i$,
$\vec{p}_B(\vec{\beta}) = \sum_i \beta_i \vec{b}_i$

2. Impose the constraint that the prefactors are normalized

$\sum_i \alpha_i^2 = 1$, 
$\sum_i \beta_i^2 = 1$

3. Define the cosine between the two vectors as their dot product
   $$\cos_{AB} = \vec{p}_A \cdot \vec{p}_B = \sum_{ij} M_{ij} \alpha_i \beta_j$$
   Where $M_{ij} = \vec{a}_i \cdot \vec{b}_j$
4. Use Lagrange multipliers to search for extrema of $\cos_{AB}$ subject to the normalization constraints. I have found that the solutions to this equation are the eigenvalues of the following matrix

$$\cos^2_{AB} = \mathrm{eval}(MM^T)$$

This is as far as I got so far.

**Questions**:

- Has somebody tried finding angle between PCA vector spaces?
- If they have done it my way, how to interpret the eigenvalues I have found?
- Can I convert the eigenvalues to a single number that would tell me how different are the vector spaces?
- If there already is a canonical method to solve this question, what is it called?

Comment: I guess I miss something, but why not simply calculate the cosine between the eigenvectors two by two following their ranks ?

Comment: It's unclear whether PCA buys you anything except complication.  Why not analyze the original data?

Comment: @manu190466 Let's say that the first two eigenvalues are exactly the same for two conditions, but their order happens to be swapped. In this case, together the two eigenvalues describe the same space, but that fact is not completely obvious from looking at the pairwise angles

Comment: @whuber Please tell me exactly what you are suggesting. I'm very positive about hearing any suggestions. I have samples from two multivariate probability distributions. I want to know in what way are the probability distributions different. I can calculate the rank-sum test to find out if the means are different - it happens not to be the case. What other tests can I perform to explore the differences between the distributions?

Comment: You state your question in terms of comparing the "major axes of variance." Thus, without challenging how meaningful this might be, we may frame it as a problem of comparing eigendirections between two datasets.  There are many ways one might devise to do that.  Most ultimately will derive from (a) a metric to compare the directions (this would be a metric on the Grassmannian manifold, evidently) and (b) a hypothesis that permits you to assess the sampling variability of that metric; barring such a hypothesis, bootstrapping would be one approach.

Comment: @whuber Thanks, that is a nice summary. I am happy if you challenge the meaningfulness of the approach as well. I would be happy to take a method off the shelf instead of inventing my own. If possible, could you recommend what approaches people use in practice? I repeat the question: How to continue exploring differences between samples of two multivariate distributions, if marginal 1D distributions do not appear significantly different

Comment: A powerful and effective method to compare multivariate data is used by the `ecp` package in `R`. It references two papers, Szekely GJ, Rizzo ML (2005). "Hierarchical Clustering Via Joint Between-Within Distances: Extending Ward's Minimum Variance Method." Journal of Classification, 22(2), 151-183 and Szekely GJ, Rizzo ML (2010). "Disco Analysis: A Nonparametric Extension of Analysis of Variance." The Annals of Applied Statistics, 4(2), 1034-1055.  The [ecp vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ecp/vignettes/ecp.pdf) has a nice explanation of how this works.

Comment: @whuber thanks a lot, I'll have a read!